Is there a REST API for getting PowerBI data?
I want to be very clear about this. I am NOT trying to use an API as a datasource for PowerBI. I am trying to find out if PowerBI has an API to retrieve data from a project. Basically I want to embed the data into a website, but I want to work with the data directly and build the UI myself instead of iframing it.
I'm only asking here because Google keeps thinking I want to use an API as a datasource. I can't find anything about if this is possible.

Yes Power BI has API to show charts, update data, or even make new reports.
You can find detailed documentation and examples for using the Power BI REST API on the official Microsoft Power BI developer documentation website. This documentation includes information on authentication, endpoints, request and response formats, and code samples in various programming languages which you will need to access with.
An example in python could be like this:
import requests

# Authenticate with Power BI API (replace with actual authentication process)
auth_token = get_auth_token()

# Specify the dataset ID
dataset_id = "your_dataset_id"

# Send a request to retrieve data from the dataset
response = requests.get(f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{dataset_id}/tables")

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Get the data from the response (assuming it's in JSON format)
    data = response.json()
    
    # Do something with the data, like print it
    print(data)
else:
    # If the request was not successful, print an error message
    print("Error: Unable to retrieve data from Power BI API")

